Ubuntu Desktop not working and network is lost
My Ubuntu is not working and the network is lost. Moreover, I kept receiving errors about disks when I tried to press Esc or entering Vim and use up or down arrow.
Error log:
: Clearing orphaned inode 72613903 (uid=134, gid=141, mode=0100600, size=0)
: Clearing orphaned inode 72613902 (uid=134, gid=141, mode=0100600, size=0)
: Clearing orphaned inode 72613901 (uid=134, gid=141, mode=0100600, size=0)
: Clearing orphaned inode 72613893 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0) 
: clean, 10936402/113721344 files, 396743006/454855680 blocks
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/525b84cd-ca0f-4a74-a77f-e90225536839.
Dependency failed for data.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/ebe29dc2-73a5-48da-a76a-1922657ec4bc.
Dependency failed for data20/2T-HDD.
Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/d57b64e2-03d9-4a13-abc9-cbf75cf3f54e.
Dependency failed for /data20/8T-HDD.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/e7416470-f817-4915-ab91-011a4c0b3eb1.
Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/e7416470-f817-4915-ab91-011a4c0b3eb1.
Dependency failed for Swaр.
Tined out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/eb5b4bd2-cf98-4bdc-a2d9-9e3bb0f571f4.
Dependency failed for /data20/1T-SSD.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/a815f4bf-783d-44c9-8c62-43c716f53e0a.
Dependency failed for /data19/BT-HDD.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/ebf1203d-9c04-4155-925d-ecbc3a685bb8.
Dependency failed for /data19/1T-SSD.
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/9f648936-f3de-4f4c-adbd-c3d41c40bf42.
Dependency failed for /data19/2T-HDD.
Failed to start Service for snap application cups.cups-browsed.
Failed to start Service for snap application cups.cupsd.
Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Does anyone know how to deal with this condition?
My Ubuntu is 20.04 version and I believe I broke the system with consecutive sudo apt autoremove” and sudo apt upgrade` .
I tried to directly use ip addr add to connect it to the network, but I don't think it works.
Is there any chance that I could fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu?
I want to keep the data in this server as much as possible. Therefore I am considering making a bootable USB by following the method I found here.
If I had to reinstall, am I going to keep the data by following above method?
